# How to get current date correctly?

Tags: java, date

I tried to get the current date in a specific format, but instead of the month got minutes

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class CurrentDate {

    public static String currentDate() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return timeStamp;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println(currentDate());
    }

}
```

Why this code gives minutes ... i tried mon ... ???

Comment: Javadoc exists for a reason.

Comment: Nowadays, use *java.time* classes. `LocalDate.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `"MM/dd/yyyy"` in the `SimpleDateFormat`.  If you look at the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html you'll see that lower case m always means minutes, and capital M is month.

Answer (score 2):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

`m` for minutes
`M` for Month